# why doesn't my image show on angular 2/4 css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Im doing a hero image for my angular website and the image is not showing up. I don't know why

My html

```
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1 style="font-size:50px">I am John Doe</h1>
    <p>And I'm a Photographer</p>
    <button>Hire me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

My css

```
.hero-image {
   background-image: url("https://newsi.creativecow.com/i/879292/2.jpeg");
   height: 50%;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   position: relative;
}

.hero-text {
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   color: black;
}
```

Comment: Where are the template and css being declared? Are the styles inline as `styles` or referenced under `styleUrls`? Show the component with these references.

Comment: it is under styleurls.

Comment: Show use then code then please. If I just drop this into my own component it works just fine.

Comment: that is strange. so you just confirmed that the code works. hmmm i wonder what's the problem. the text shows but the image doesn't

Comment: I have no idea, since I cannot see your code despite asking you to actually post it in your question several times now. I'll go out on a limb here and guess that other people are going to come to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute height 50% won't work unless there is text in there first div tag. Create an image tag inside div.

Hope this helps:

```css
.hero-image {
   background-image: url("https://newsi.creativecow.com/i/879292/2.jpeg");
   height: 500px; /* Change Accordingly */
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   position: relative;
}

.hero-text {
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1 style="font-size:50px">I am John Doe</h1>
    <p>And I'm a Photographer</p>
    <button>Hire me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can not give height as % in above case. You should inherit it.

Comment: you can also give image tag inside div to display image. If you prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

Well,I dont know very well what you want to do after, but one solution is write your `div-class hero-image` as absolute position, but for this case I guess that the reference will be the body and I dont know if you want that solution, and another thing is write  `width: 100%;`

summary:

```
.hero-image {
 background-image: url("https://newsi.creativecow.com/i/879292/2.jpeg");
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: i had to change the height from percentage to px thank you tho